# Shortcut to configure network setting

Tags: networking, keyboard-shortcuts, lan

I don't know if it is possible but... let's try!

As I often need to change my network settings (ip address, netmask and default gateway) is ther a way to create a shortcut to reset the network card configuration to a default state (of my choice)?

For example I would like to have a shortcut that will apply the configuration (ip, netmask and gw) for my office LAN.

many thanks,
Andrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shortcut can be created for a `.bat` file that contains a
[Netsh command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc738592(v=ws.10)).

Its general syntax is:

```
set address [name=]InterfaceName [source=]{dhcp | static [addr=]IPAddress[mask=]SubnetMask [gateway=]{none | DefaultGateway [[gwmetric=]GatewayMetric]}}
```

For example:

```
set address name="Local Area Connection" source=static addr=10.0.5.99 mask=255.255.255.0 gateway=10.0.5.1 gwmetric=1
```

Comment: Hey @harrymc, very nice and smart idea! :)  
  
BTW, the correct syntax needs also the parameter 'interface ipv4'.  
So the complete command is:  
'netsh interface ipv4 set address name="LAN Fisica" source=static addr=10.0.5.99 mask=255.255.255.0 gateway=10.0.5.1 gwmetric=1'  
  
In this way it works great!  
Of course the command could need administrative privileges.  
Thanks!!